# Ruby crashes on windows on using thin+ssl

Tags: ruby, windows, ssl, thin, msvcr90.dll

I am using ruby on windows(ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [i386-mswin32_90]). And in my gemfile i have following:-

```
gem 'rack',                      '1.4.5'
gem 'thin',                      '1.5.0'
```

Problem is when i am trying to start thin with ssl option by specifying :-

```
ruby bin/thin --ssl  -a 127.0.0.1 -p 44466 start
```

I starts the server, but on accessing the `https://localhost:44466`. I crashes ruby and gives the error on console and a popup comes saying ruby interpretor has stopped working.

`"This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information."`

```
Faulting application name: ruby.exe, version: 1.9.3.194, time stamp: 0x5154804d
Faulting module name: MSVCR90.dll, version: 9.0.30729.4940, time stamp: 0x4ca2ef57
Exception code: 0x40000015
Fault offset: 0x0005beae
Faulting process id: 0x11d4
Faulting application start time: 0x01cf7fb6cca849aa
Faulting application path: C:\Ruby19\bin\ruby.exe
Faulting module path:C:\Windows\WinSx\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4940_none_50916076bcb9a742\MSVCR90.dll
```

Report Id: 47c368b9-ebaa-11e3-8cd8-8c89a5d53bc0`

I tried diff versions of ruby and openssl . but no luck. I am on windows platform and compiliing using microsoft visual studio8. Please let me know if i am missing some steps. how can remove/avoid this 'msvcr90.dll' error.

```
 platform :- windows7
 Ruby :- ruby1.9.3p194 / ruby1.9.3p545
 Openssl :- openssl 1.0.0d/openssl 1.0.0e
```

Please suggest if i am missing anything, if ruby1.9.3 mswin has some issues with thin ssl?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think there were some problem with SSL in some 1.9.3 version. So I suggest try to download new version(1.9.x may be ok) and try again.

Comment: Due to some dependecy on other things, i am bound to use the same version. Can you suggest if i try any other option?

Comment: Also, i tried installing thin and eventmachine using options with-ssl-dir. It gives me error `C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file
. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.` Can you tell me wher can i get devkit for mswinruby 193

Comment: Well, as for your 2nd question, check this: http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ but I don‘t what this packages has. For the first question, you can try other SSL gems, but I do not know how to set this in the rack/thin.

Answer (score 1):

After a long follow up and trying out compilation various times on windows, I got to know the reason.

Main culprit was evenmachine gem. The eventmachine gem was built with WITHOUT_SSL macro on MSVC Compiler. And thin internally uses eventmachine and this was causing ruby to crash.

Compiling event machine gem after changin extconf.rb worked for me.

```
diff --git a/extconf.rb b/extconf.rb.new
index 448802a..27a5b8b 100644
--- a/extconf.rb
+++ b/extconf.rb.new
@@ -25,7 +25,7 @@ end
def manual_ssl_config
  ssl_libs_heads_args = {
    :unix => [%w[ssl crypto], %w[openssl/ssl.h openssl/err.h]],
  -    :mswin => [%w[ssleay32 eay32], %w[openssl/ssl.h openssl/err.h]],
  +    :mswin => [%w[ssleay32 libeay32], %w[openssl/ssl.h openssl/err.h]],
  }

dc_flags = ['ssl']
```