# Can't setup SSL with thin in development on windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ssl, https, thin

I need to set up `https` in my development env and I've run out of options. Everything I have tried all give the same error when I go to `https://localhost:3001` I'm fairly sure that the problem has something to do with `eventmachine` and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23906850/ruby-crashes-on-windows-on-using-thinssl) stackoverflow post, but I don't know how to apply it to test it. If anyone can help me out that would be amazing.

```
Using rack adapter
Thin web server (v1.6.4 codename Gob Bluth)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 0.0.0.0:3001, CTRL+C to stop
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Encryption not available on this event-machine

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Here's what I've tried:

I tried the normal `force_ssl` with:

`application.rb`

```
class Application < Rails::Application
  config.force_ssl = false
```

`development.rb`

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.force_ssl = true
```

`application_controller.rb`

```
force_ssl
```

`/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.ssl
```

Then I start one server with `thin start -p 3000` and I've tried both `thin start -p 3001 --ssl --ssl-key-file C:/.ssl/server.key --ssl-cert-file C:/.ssl/server.crt` and the regular `thin start --ssl -p 3001` When I go to `https://localhost:3000` I get this error (in terminal that's running `-p 3000`):

```
Invalid request: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails.
    C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/request.rb:84:in `execute'
    C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/request.rb:84:in `parse'
    C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
    C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/eventmachine-076a526915dc/lib/eventmachine.rb:194:in `run_machine'
    C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/eventmachine-076a526915dc/lib/eventmachine.rb:194:in `run'
    C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
    C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
    C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:87:in `start'
    C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/runner.rb:200:in `run_command'
    C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/runner.rb:156:in `run!'
    C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
    C:/Ruby200/bin/thin:23:in `load'
    C:/Ruby200/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
```

Then I followed this [tutorial](http://makandracards.com/makandra/15903-using-thin-for-development-with-ssl) and made the necessary corrections for windows.

`config/initializers/force_ssl_patch.rb`

```
ActionController::ForceSSL::ClassMethods.module_eval do
  def force_ssl(options = {})
    config = Rails.application.config

    return unless config.use_ssl # <= this is new

    host = options.delete(:host)
    port = config.ssl_port if config.respond_to?(:ssl_port) && config.ssl_port.present? # <= this is also new

    before_filter(options) do
      if !request.ssl?# && !Rails.env.development? # commented out the exclusion of the development environment
        redirect_options = {:protocol => 'https://', :status => :moved_permanently}
        redirect_options.merge!(:host => host) if host
        redirect_options.merge!(:port => port) if port # <= this is also new
        redirect_options.merge!(:params => request.query_parameters)
        redirect_to redirect_options
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to recompile EventMachine with OpenSSL support as described here: https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/wiki/Building-EventMachine-with-SSL-on-Windows